# Padding Numbers and Truncating them in Python

Tags: python, truncate, pad

Im currently writing a program in python and i need to be able to truncate the number after 2 decimal places and align it in a table. However, i am unsure how to truncate AND pad my output. Here is the code i want to alter that currently has truncation.

```
print(month_count,'\t','\t',monthly_payment,'\t','\t',"%.2f" % '%d' % interest_amount,'\t','\t',"%.2f" % loan)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `.format()` for both truncation and alignment:

```
In [6]: '{:>10.2f}'.format(1000.00001)
Out[6]: '   1000.00'
```

`>10` part means right adjusted with total of 10 characters. 
`.2f` means keep only 2 decimal places.

See https://pyformat.info/ for more